# Why 'CSV' is most preferable in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, csv

I am new to ruby on rails. I just want to know why ruby on rails use `csv` files rather than `xls` files, though both are used to store the tabular values, why `csv` is commonly used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSV is a simple text format, and readily parsed, whereas XLS is a proprietary binary format. Why put your code through loops to load, open and iterate Excel data structures when you can simply process a text file for the same end?

Comment: check https://rubygems.org/gems/axlsx and then you will see generating a csv is nobraner whether creating an xlsx file is a pain

Comment: Explain what? What else do you need to know? It's infinitely preferable (and simpler) to parse data from a CSV file than it is from an Excel file, so if a tabular text format suits your requirement, CSV is enough.

Comment: Here's an example: open a CSV with a text editor (notepad).  Then do the same with an XLS in a text editor.  Then tell us which format you'd rather work with.